# How to get entity id of newly created entity using entity_get_controller

Tags: drupal-7

I am crating the new entity in drupal a below,

```
$entity = new stdClass();
$entity->type = 'entity_type';
$entity->id = 0;
$entity->title = 'Entity Title';

//Add data to fields
$entity->field_introduction = array
            (
                'und' => array
                (
                    "0" => array
                    (
                        'value' => $strIntroduction
                    )
                )
            );

 .
 .
 .
 .


//After adding all the fields, I am saving entity as follows,

entity_get_controller('summary_report')->save($entity);
```

Entity get saved successfully. After this I want entity id for the further manipulations. How I get this newly created entity id.

Answer (score 0):

`$entity` will contain your ID as object gets filled with all the data after saving the entity. Data returned from `save()` method is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Hope this helps.